# User profile options setting is not reflecting immediately after session logout in EBS 12.2.4 instances

Tags: oracle, oracle-ebs

We need to do "ICX:Forms Launcher" setting to a particular user in my EBS instances.

When I do this user level setting for a user in EBS instances below 12.2.4 version (means 12.1.3), changes are reflecting after session logout and login.

But for 12.2.4 instances, user profile options are not reflecting after session logout and login.

We observed that after some "x" amount of time/after restart, changes are affecting.

```
Please help us on how to get user profile setting changes immediately for a user in 12.2.4.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Profiles are cached at a couple of different levels in EBS (PL/SQL, java).  Even after logging out and back in you may get the same JDBC connection or AM and hence the cached profiles (they will time out).  Whether you do or not will depend on a variety of factors - pool settings, load of the system.

I don't know if anything that changed in the caching of profiles between 12.1 and 12.2.  Although the JDBC cache did change which may impact this.  Is this behavior consistent under different loads across the versions?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. Actually, we have tested only few 12.1.3 instances. As you said may be it is not the problem with 12.24. Caching problem seems. Can you please share me the documentation link having this caching information.

Comment: Got the info from the below link. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18727_01/doc.121/e12894/T202991T202994.htm

Comment: Yes - that's the correct document for clearing the cache - should be applicable for 12.2 as well

Comment: Hi, We have not tested yet. I will acknowledge here after testing.

Comment: Hi, after clearing PROFILE_OPTION_VALUE_CACHE, user profile settings are reflecting. It's working fine!!!.